# Is there a way to input a unique number for each array output?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am trying to number each result so that it says:

City #1 is Los Angeles.
City #2 is San Francisco.
City #3 is... and so on.

I was thinking that I had to write something inside the for loop?

I am working with Notepad++.

```
<html>
 
<body style="text-align: center;">
 
    <h2 id="hi">Enter Your Five Favorite Cities</h2>
    <form class="" action="index.html">
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
    <br>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="favoriteCities()">Submit</button>
   
    </form>
 
    <h3 id="hi">Results</h3>
 
    <p id="output"></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var r = "";
        function favoriteCities() {
            var input = document.getElementsByName('favoriteCities[]');
 
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                var a = input[i];
                r = r + "City #" + "???" + "is " + a.value + ("<br>");
            }
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = r;
        }
    </script>
    
    
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: The `i` index you use in the loop is an `unique number`, so `r = r + "City " + i + " is " + a.value + ("<br>");` or something?

Answer (score 1):

As quoted, you can use the index of the loop to know the city count.

```js
var r = "";
function favoriteCities() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName('favoriteCities[]');

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var a = input[i];
        r = r + "City #" + ( i + 1 ) + " is " + a.value + ("<br>");
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = r;
}
```

```html
    <h2 id="hi">Enter Your Five Favorite Cities</h2>
    <form class="" action="index.html">
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="favoriteCities[]" value="" /><br>
    <br>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="favoriteCities()">Submit</button>
   
    </form>
 
    <h3 id="hi">Results</h3>
 
    <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to remove all that concatenation.

Comment: Absolutely true, but in my very humble opinion, I doubt it's within the OPs current level of JS experience. So including templates would only confuse them.